# I don't want to use the time_of_day parameter in MakeServiceAreaAnalysisLayer, what do I put to miss it?

Tags: arcpy, network-analyst, arcgis-pro, error-000628

I'm modelling accessibility, so am using network analyst arcpy.na.MakeServiceAreaAnalysisLayer().

However, I don't want to enter anything for the time_of_day parameter. How do I write my Python script so that I can write parameters after this, but not include time_of_day or time_zone?

I get `ERROR 000628: Cannot set input into parameter time_of_day.`

I'm a newbie to scripting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not wish to enter a value for a parameter, you'd typically pass it an empty string. The time_of_day parameter is the 6th parameter (or so I read from the doc).

```
arcpy.na.MakeServiceAreaAnalysisLayer(network, layer_name,
                                                travel_mode, "FROM_FACILITIES",
                                                [3], "", polygon_detail="HIGH",
                                                geometry_at_overlaps="OVERLAP")
```

However, only the input network parameter is required. You should be able to run the tool just like:

```
arcpy.na.MakeServiceAreaAnalysisLayer(network)
```

Or, if you only want to provide one optional parameter that isn't the first and *not* pass in a bunch of empty strings, you can pass a value to the assigned parameter like so:

```
arcpy.na.MakeServiceAreaAnalysisLayer(network, geometry_at_overlaps="OVERLAP")
```

(The geometry_at_overlaps is actually the 10th parameter)

To answer the question in the comment, how to use all parameters up till geometry_at_cutoffs, but skipping time_of_day and time_zone:

```
arcpy.na.MakeServiceAreaAnalysisLayer(network, layer_name,
                                    travel_mode, "FROM_FACILITIES", [1, 2, 3],
                                    time_of_day="",
                                    time_zone="",
                                    output_type="LINES",
                                    polygon_detail="HIGH",
                                    geometry_at_overlaps="OVERLAP",
                                    geometry_at_cutoffs="RINGS")
```

(I started making them named parameters for ease of seeing what parameter is where)

Comment: Thank you, thats helpful! Although I want to use parameters up until geometry_at_cutoffs, just missing the time_of_day and time_zone, would the above still be applicable?

Comment: Good answer. I would include a link to the official documentation: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/network-analyst/make-service-area-analysis-layer.htm

Comment: @JGe I added one more example for what you're doing specifically.